# update from temp table to original table

Tags: oracle

I have two tables one is original table and second one is temp table. Temp table having the correct record. Unique column is cust_id. My table structure is

Customer table

```
cust_id  amount
12       100
13       120
14       130
15       250
20        70
25       110
28       900

temp table 

cust_id  amount
12       300
13       190
14       110
15       240
20        30
25       210
28       500
```

I want to update the record from temp table to customer orignal table using customer id.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I don't knew that please tel me

Comment: You didn't have an attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081218) statement.

```
merge into original_table ot
using temp_table tp
  on (ot.cust_id = tp.cust_id)
when matched 
then update set ot.amount = tp. amount
```